# cannot import 'AutoModelForSequenceClassification' from 'transformers'

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

**cannot import 'AutoModelForSequenceClassification' from 'transformers'**

The code is

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification, pipeline

t = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('/some/directory')
m = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('/some/directory')
c2 = pipeline(task = 'sentiment-analysis', model=m, tokenizer=t)
```

The error is

```
cannot import 'AutoModelForSequenceClassification' from 'transformers'
```

Comment: What's the transformers version?

Comment: It's working now. I've installed 4.3.3

Answer (score 0):

```html
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, BertForSequenceClassification
from transformers import (XLMRobertaConfig, XLMRobertaTokenizer, TFXLMRobertaModel)            
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoConfig, TFAutoModel    

PRETRAINED_MODEL_TYPES = {
    'xlmroberta': (AutoConfig, AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoTokenizer, 'akhooli/xlm-r-large-arabic-toxic')
}

# model_class,model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("akhooli/xlm-r-large-arabic-toxic")

config_class, model_class, tokenizer_class, model_name = PRETRAINED_MODEL_TYPES['xlmroberta']

# Download vocabulary from huggingface.co and cache.
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name,use_fast=False) #fast tokenizer

tokenizer
```